# How to show that $\nabla \times \vec{r}/{|\vec{r}|} = 0$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, vector-fields

That's basically it:
$$\nabla \times \frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|} = 0$$

There's some connection with physical significance of curl of vector function. I am currently in Grade 10 but am in a preparatory physics course. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I have so far,

\begin{bmatrix}         \hat r & \hat \theta & \hat \phi \\         \frac{\partial}{\partial r}  & \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \\         \frac{1}{r^2} & 0 & 0 \\         \end{bmatrix}

which gives me 0 since \begin{equation}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\frac{1}{r^2}) \end{equation} and \begin{equation}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\frac{1}{r^2}) \end{equation} are equal to zero. However, I feel this isn't the right method.

Comment: Welcome to PSE, please try to provide a hint of what you know and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please just edit the question to add work you've done instead of making large comments on the question. This is so the question itself is self contained.

Comment: Could you define what $\textbf{r}$ is? The radius of a sphere?

Comment: Wellcome @SleepFinnegan. You are close, but the vectorial product is wrong. You didn't write the operator $\nabla$ properly in spherical coordinates. You can look for the proper form in any calculus table, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates).

Comment: Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013153/finding-curl-in-spherical-coordinates

Comment: Also the curl gives a sense of the rotational properties of a vector field, if you plotted your vector field would you say that identity makes physical sense?

Answer (score 3):

In Cartesian coordinates the $i$th component is$$\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(x_k/r)\stackrel{\ast}{=}\epsilon_{ijk}(\delta_{jk}/r-r^{-3}x_jx_k)=0$$(with [implicit summation over repeated indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)), because we've contracted a $j\leftrightarrow k$-antisymmetric Levi-Civita symbol with a $j\leftrightarrow k$-symmetric tensor. For $\stackrel{\ast}{=}$, we use the product rule plus$$\partial_jr^{-1}=-r^{-2}\partial_jr=-\frac12r^{-3}\partial_j(r^2)=-\frac12r^{-3}\partial_j(x_kx_k)=-\frac12r^{-3}2\delta_{jk}x_k=-r^{-3}x_j.$$

Answer (score 2):

First we have no need to use spherical coordinates. Cartesian do the work as well. We have:
$$
\vec{r} = (x,y,z) \implies r = |\vec{r}| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \\
\implies \frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|} = 
\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}, \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} \right)
$$

Then

$$\nabla \times \frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|} = \hat{i}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} - \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right) - \hat{j}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} - \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right) + \hat{k}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)$$

This gives you

$$\nabla \times \frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|} = \hat{i}\left(-\frac{y z}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}} +\frac{y z}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}} \right) - \hat{j}\left(-\frac{x z}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}} +\frac{x z}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}\right) + \hat{k}\left(-\frac{x y}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}} +\frac{x y}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}\right)$$

Which as you can see makes zero.

Answer (score 2):

There's a very important identity: $\nabla \times \nabla V=0$ for any scalar $V$, regardless of coordinate system. The curl of a gradient is always zero. So first prove or note you are using that theorem, then prove that the vector in question is a gradient of some scalar.

[Stoke's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem#Theorem) establishes an equality between the curl's surface integral and a line integral of the gradient. A closed line integral of a gradient is zero, so the surface integral must be zero. The surface integral can only be zero if the integrand is always zero, i.e. $\nabla \times \nabla V=0$.

Suppose $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ .Then $\nabla r=\frac{x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}}{r}=\frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|}$.

So let $V=r$, apply the identity, and you are done.